# Division with polynomial equations (multiple methods)

Tags: polynomials

I can use the quadratic formula to solve for x using a polynomial equation. So there should be more than one way to solve for it then, right? So let's say that you need to solve $2x^2 - 3x + 5 = 0$ using any division method. What method would be the most correct?

Comment: This is not clear.  The quadratic formula finds all solutions, real and complex.

Comment: I know that the quadratic formula finds all solutions. I want to know if there are more than one way to find the solution. In other words other methods to solve it.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  You appear to imagine that different methods will produce different solutions, but of course they will not.

Comment: As to different methods, you can complete the squares if you like.  I have no idea what you mean by a "division method".  Of course, if you know one root (through whatever means) then it is easy to find the other.

Comment: I get that the solutions will be the same. I am interested, in the fact that there are usually more than one way to solve for it.

Comment: Then I suggest editing your post.  Your suggestion that, because some of the roots might be complex, it follows that there should be more than one way to solve the equation is very confusing.

Comment: [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) works well for (numerically) finding real roots.  To adapt it to find complex roots, write a complex root as $a+bi$ and expand to get two equations, in real, $a,b$ which can then be found numerically.  This is a good method for solving general problems...clearly overkill in the case of quadratics.

Comment: The Newton's Method looks like overkill in quadratics, but it still would work. That method might help me out later. This looks like an interesting method.

Comment: It is a very good and very powerful method.  Absolutely worth learning.  Even for quadratics...something like the quadratic formula tends to yield answers with radical terms.  Newton gives you an excellent way to convert those radicals into real numbers (at least approximately).

Comment: Then I might just learn it then. It might take me a while to learn it but it looks like it will become useful in the future. Also I want to know what math level is the Newton Method?

Comment: Calculus. For things like quadratics, or just for finding square roots numerically, it is very old...known as the Babylonian method for finding square roots.  You can certainly learn that method with no calculus.